# calculating ANOVA 'by hand'

Tags: r, anova

I've calculated an ANOVA in R using the `aov()` function, then calculated it semi-manually using my own code. I'm interested in why my mean sum of squares between groups (0.634443) is not the same as that outputted by `aov()` (0.4145), and yet my mean sum of squares within groups is the same as that outputted by `aov()`?

```
# create fake data
set.seed(50)
x = data.frame(length=rnorm(9), 
               site = c(rep('a', 3), 
                        rep('b', 3), 
                        rep('c', 3)), stringsAsFactors=F)
# ANOVA summary
summary(aov(length ~ factor(site), x))
# Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
# factor(site)  2  0.829  0.4145   0.514  0.622
# Residuals     6  4.840  0.8067 

# calculate sum of squares within, between and total
sumlength <- sum(x$length)   
    n = 3
    overallMean <- sumlength/n
    aMean <- mean(x$length[x$site=="a"])
    bMean <- mean(x$length[x$site=="b"])
    cMean <- mean(x$length[x$site=="c"]) 

ssw <- sum((x$length[x$site == 'a'] - aMean) * (x$length[x$site == 'a'] - aMean)) + 
            sum((x$length[x$site == 'b'] - bMean) * (x$length[x$site == 'b'] - 
            bMean)) + sum((x$length[x$site == 'c'] - cMean) * (x$length[x$site == 
            'c'] - cMean))  
sst <- sum((x$length - overallMean) * (x$length - overallMean))  
ssb <- ((aMean - overallMean) * (aMean - overallMean) + (bMean - overallMean) * 
        (bMean - overallMean) + (cMean - overallMean) * (cMean - overallMean)) * 3

meanSsb <- ssb/2     # 0.634443
meanSsw <- ssw/6     # 0.8066979
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**output:**

```
summary(aov(length ~ factor(site), x))
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
factor(site)  2  0.829  0.4145   0.514  0.622
Residuals     6  4.840  0.8067
```

---

`overallmean` should be the overall mean

> overallmean <- mean(x$length)

(you divided by 3 rather than dividing by 9).

---

To get the sum of squares for `site`, you need to compute
$$
\sum_i n_i \,(\bar{Y}_{i\cdot} - \bar{Y}_{\cdot\cdot})^2
$$
i.e., the sum of weighted (with weights equal to $n_1, n_2, \dotsc$) squared deviations of each estimated factor level mean ($\bar{Y}_{i\cdot}$) around the overall mean ($\bar{Y}_{\cdot\cdot}$).

In R, (using the same kind of calculations as you)

```
na <- nrow(x[x$site == "a", ])
nb <- nrow(x[x$site == "b", ])
nc <- nrow(x[x$site == "c", ])

aMean <- mean(x[x$site == "a", "length"])
bMean <- mean(x[x$site == "b", "length"])
cMean <- mean(x[x$site == "c", "length"])

sum(na * (aMean - overallmean)^2 + 
    nb * (bMean - overallmean)^2 + 
    nc * (cMean - overallmean)^2)
[1] 0.8290974
```

---

To get the residual sum of squares, you need 
$$
\sum_i \sum_j (Y_{ij} - \bar{Y}_{i\cdot})^2
$$
i.e., the sum of squared deviations of each observation ($Y_{ij}$) around its estimated factor level mean ($\bar{Y}_{i\cdot}$)

```
sum(c((x[x$site == "a", "length"] - aMean)^2,
      (x[x$site == "b", "length"] - bMean)^2,
      (x[x$site == "c", "length"] - cMean)^2))
[1] 4.840187
```

Comment: I'm trying to describe you're residuals sum of squares equation in words. Could you tell me if this is correct: 'for every value j in every group i, minus the mean of group i, and square the result. Finally, sum all of the values i in all groups j'.

Comment: I have made an edit to make it more explicit. But, yes, you are correct.

Comment: I've mixed up i and j in final part of sentence. Are you able to edit this (I'm not)?

Comment: Take observation $j$ of group $i$: $Y_{ij}$. Because $Y_{ij}$ belongs to group $i$, subtract the estimated mean of group $i$: $Y_{ij} - \bar{Y}_{i\cdot}$. Square: $(Y_{ij} - \bar{Y}_{i\cdot})^2$. Repeat for all $j$ and $i$ and sum: $\sum_i \sum_j (Y_{ij} - \bar{Y}_{i\cdot})^2$.

Answer (score 7):

Look at the line `n = 3`.  The overall number of data points is 9, not 3, so when you calculate the overall mean you are dividing the sum of 9 numbers by 3, so your mean is not the mean.  Change that to `n = 9` and it looks like it matches to me.